# Get dynamically loaded source in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm trying to get page content which is *dynamically loaded* after you get to the end of the page but after use `sendKeys(Keys.END)` page content seems to be the same.

Any chance to handle it and get new reloaded source? I'm using PhantomJS in Java.

Comment: Please post the html you are targeting and the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to **[explicitly wait](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) for a presence or visibility of an element loaded dynamically** - then, call the `getPageSource()` method.

For example, if there is a `div` with a "additionalContent" class dynamically loaded, here is how you can wait for it to appear:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.additionalContent")));

// get the page source
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```